# Tkinter: change color of the top bar of window

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I change the color of the top bar of a simple Tkinter window ?

Here is my simple code showing where I want to change the color:

```
from Tkinter import *
class Mine:
   def __init__(self,master):
       framev=Frame(master)
       framev.grid(row=0,column=0)
if __name__=="__main__":
   root=Tk()
   root.wm_title("I want to change the color of THIS area")
   m=Mine(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's most likely not possible as the title bar is rendered by the system's window manager.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change the border and top part of a window. That area is beyond the control of tkinter. You can completely remove it and draw your own, but then you lose the minimize, maximize and quit buttons and have to implement them yourself.